# Update the Author field and capture the Last Modified Date for Existing documents in Modern SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, modern-experience, power-automate

I've copied over 700 documents into a SharePoint library and I would like do two things:

1. I would like the Author column to display the original document
   Author property
2. I created a new **Last Modified Date** column, and
   I would like to display the original documents Last Modified Date
   (Not the date I uploaded it).

Is there an easy way to get that information to update?

I've looked all over for steps to create a Power Automate flow but I haven't found one. I'm a newbie at this but if someone can provide the steps I could create it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial. You will need to extract the Author and Last Modified Date from the files. This means you will probably need to cater for Office files, pdf, images, emails, ...
Note: some file formats do not contain this information (e.g. zip, txt, ...).

There are 3rd party apps that offer this capability but the extraction of the properties is done during uploading.